# Curl could not open file with bracket [] in form-field

Tags: curl

I'm working with an api (phaxio) that specifies to:

> Put square brackets after parameter name to send multiple files (e.g. filename[])

However when I put square after the form-field I get a couldn't open file error.

```
touch /foo
curl http://example.org -F "filename[]=@/foo"   // curl: (26) couldn't open file "/foo"
curl http://example.org -F "filename=@/foo"     // works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using it on windows and there must be something wrong with the curl implementation on windows.

Works fine on linux--I just didn't think to try it there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by doing this.

```
touch /foo
touch /bar
curl http://example.org -F "filename[0]=@/foo"
curl http://example.org -F "filename[1]=@/bar"
```

Notice in my example I am demonstrating sending multiple files as I understand that is your intention to do.